# How to write a regex pattern that allows optional star(*) character at the end

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex pattern to match values e.g. `A12`, `A12.1`, `A12.12`, `A12.1*`

Here is the pattern that I already have which seems to work for all cases except when optional star character is added to the end. It should work both with and without the star sign at the end.

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: Simply replace `\d{1,2}` with `.{1,2}`: `[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\..{1,2})?`

Comment: At the end add  \\*?

Comment: I also got to this solution which works: `[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\.\d{1,2}\*?)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an optional literal *

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?\*?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\.\d{1,2}\*\|\.\d{1,2})?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add [*]?

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?[*]?
```